# Please enter the correct Email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-user, superuser, user-mode-linux

I complete makemigrations and migrate then create a superuser. After this
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin i try to log in then show this error
***Please enter the correct Email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive***

**seetings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.CustomUser'


**models.py**
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email id')

        user=self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user=self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    #only add email field for login

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email',
        max_length=50,
        unique=True
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email



***admin.py***

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user=get_user_model()

admin.site.register(user)
```

Comment: Are you sure re-create method `create_superuser`? 
Maybe password must be `make_password(password)`.

Example like `def create_superuser` in `UserManager`. Here is django code:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py

Comment: In method `def  _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields)`

Comment: The `password` must create using `make_password` function.

`from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`

Comment: @MahrusKhomaini Thank you for your informative comment. Now the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem.
you should define `is_staff=True` in create_superuser function and you should pass **kwargs as argument in this function.
i hope your problem solve.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue while working on my Django project. Initially, I had a server running in the background at localhost:8000 for another project. When I started a new server for my current project, it also opened at localhost:8000. The problem is that when I created a superuser, the data was submitted to the database of the initial server, not the one for the current project.
Additionally, when attempting to log in, the views from the initial server were being used instead of the ones in the current project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the `django.contrib.admin` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, and that you have run the manage.py migrate command to create the necessary database tables for the admin site.

Make sure that you have the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` and `django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware` in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting, and that you have the `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` and `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages` in your TEMPLATES setting. These are required for the admin site to work properly.

Make sure that you have the correct `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting for your domain. For example, if you are going to `https://www.example.com/admin/` in your browser, set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'www.example.com'`. You may also want to try using a different hostname for your local development, such as `‘localhost.localdomain’`. This can help avoid some issues with cookies and domains.

Alternatively, you can try setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `None` in your settings.py file. This will make the cookie domain default to the request host, which should work for localhost.

With my project, it worked when I set `SESSON_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `None`. You also got to make migrations and migrate everything. Delete the `db.sqlite3`, migrations in the migrations folder except the `__init__.py`. So that means including the pycache.